# Representing a date in JavaScript when timezone is irrelevant

Tags: javascript, api, timezone

I am working on a very small JavaScript library that allows users to retrieve content based on date. For this content, the date is just an identifier and timezones are completely irrelevant (think along the lines of a [Dilbert flip calendar](http://www.calendars.com/img/p/400/201300000398_2.jpg)). The "May 14th" content is the same whether you are in the United States or Australia.

The function for retrieving data currently takes a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as a parameter. Within the function, the timezone is ignored. Does this approach make sense, or would it be better to take a timezone-independent identifier (like *2012-01-01*) as a parameter instead? With the Date object approach, do I run the risk of returning the wrong data as a result of timezone adjustments browsers make?

Comment: Just always use UTC (which is the timezone of the internal representation of JS dates), and you won't experience much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that simply ignoring the timezone information is the best approach. Why? This will always preserve the date and time that were provided to the Date constructor (which is my goal), whereas the getUTC* methods will return altered versions of the date and time. For example, take a look at this node [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) session I ran on a computer in the Eastern Time zone.

```
> d = new Date(2013, 03, 27, 23, 00, 00)
Sat Apr 27 2013 23:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
> d.getDate() // The same date provided in the constructor. Woo!
27
> d.getUTCDate() // A different date. Boo!
28
```

Long story short, if you want to read the exact date and time that were provided in the Date constructor, using the normal get* methods (like getDate) will do that. If you use the getUTC* methods (like getUTCDate) modified versions of the date and time will be returned.

I know this may sound rudimentary to some of the more experienced programmers out there, but this really helped me make sense of things. I hope it helps others who come along.

Comment: Wait, so THIS was what you were asking for? Ha, I kinda overthinked the whole thing :)

Answer (score 2):

How about using Date.getUTC*() functions? UTC time is the same for everyone.

Comment: I think my biggest problem is just not understanding how the Date object works. If someone passes me a *Date(2011, 05, 14)* will the getUTC functions ever return a value that represents the 15th (or 13th)? Wouldn't that be the case if someone passes me a date that is one hour off from midnight GMT with a two-hour timezone offset?

Forgive me if I am not making sense here. Timezones (and Unicode) sort of make my head spin.

Comment: getUTC functions will only add (or substract) user set timezone from the current time to get UTC. So yeah, if user will pass time from the future - it will give utc time from that future. 

But then you need to remember that all javascript is in user domain. Instead of passing wrong values user could just set his computer clock to any time (or timezone) he wants.

So if you need to be sure that date info is valid - query it from the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Thank you for all of the help, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter by accident. Comment is much more elaborate now :)

Comment: @parnas: No, it's the other way round - the local methods subtract the offset from the current time. I'd suggest to use UTC, and `new Date(Date.UTC(2011, 5, 14))` (or epoch timestamps right away) for constructing the `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with the approach in your own answer is that it doesn't account for ambiguous times.  This happens during daylight savings fall-back transitions.

For example, set your computer's time zone to US Mountain Time  ("Mountain Time (US & Canada)" on windows, or "America/Denver" on mac/linux).  Then restart your browser and run the following javascript:

```
var dt = new Date(2013,10,3,1,0);
alert(dt);
```

This is November 3rd, 2013 at 1:00 AM.  But you don't know *which* 1:00 AM it is representing. Is it in Mountain Daylight Time (UTC-6) before the transition, or Mountain Standard Time (UTC-7) after?  There's no way to tell, and JavaScript will just use the standard time.

Now if all you need is `2013-11-03 01:00` - then you are correct.  You can just ignore the offset and be done with it.  But if you are going to use that value for anything meaningful - such as recording a point in time, or subtracting from another point in time for duration between them, then you have a problem that you can't resolve without the offset.

Unfortunately, there is no great solution for this problem in JavaScript.  The closest thing is [Moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com), but it is still [not perfect yet](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/611).  Still, it is better than the `Date` object by itself, because it gets around browser inconsistencies and provides better parsing and formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. In my case, I only need the users of my library to have a convenient way to represent some date in the past. A convenient way to say "March 3, 1995" or "July 15, 2010". The date never needs to represent the current time, and will never be compared against the current time. The only requirement is that the date they specify does not change between the time they specify it and the time I read it.

The Date object (with the normal get* methods) seems like a good solution to this problem, as per my own answer. Sounds like you agree in paragraph 4?

Comment: @FallingPlates - Yes, then all of your requirements are met as you described.  You should be ok. :)